# How to improve time complexity of this algorithm

Tags: algorithm, optimization, data-structures, time-complexity

Here's a simple problem: I have this array of length N, and a function that given 2 bounds (a,b) returns the sum of all the elements in the array between a and b.

Now, this is clearly O(N) time complexity... but if I wanted to make it more efficient (like log(N)), with a second data structure that stores partial sums, how could I accomplish it?

I was thinking of a binary tree but can't find an algorithm. Of course I could just create a NxN matrix but it's too much. I'd like something that doesn't require too much space and lets me have a logarithmic time complexity; any idea?

UPDATE: I didn't specify it clearly.. but:

1. the bounds are on the indexes of the array, not the values
2. the array is dynamic, values can change, and I don't want to have linear complexity to change a value! Therefore the simple algorithm of partial sums doesn't work, I think..
3. no concurrent programming (1 CPU)

Comment: You would actually only need half of an NxN matrix because a,b will work, b,a is either the same thing or invalid (or something different if it's circular and then you would need all NxN slots)

Comment: Are the bounds on the index? i.e return `A[a] + A[a+1] + .. + A[b]`? Or on the values? i.e return the sum of all `A[i]` such that `a <= A[i] <= b`? I know you talk about partial sums which seems to indicate the former, but you should clarify. -1 till you do.

Comment: Ok I see the answers, but the problem is that everytime I change a value all the partial sums must be updated, and that's O(n), while the sum function is O(1). This way you create another problem to solve the previous one!

Comment: @marco: Please edit the question with the clarification about index and that you would need to allow updates to the array values. I cannot remove my downvote unless the question is edited. And please don't accept answers which don't really answer your question (like the part about updating values).

Comment: @marco According to the answer you have accepted, it seems like you will be recurrently doing sums over an array containing fairly static information, as opposed to, say, doing a one-time sum over an interval of an array whose content is dynamic, and also that you're willing to sacrifice some space complexity by precomputing the sums for all intervals of size 1. Re binary-trees and summing over dynamic data, please see my answer below.

Comment: @marco Thank you for the update/clarification. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 10):

Well, you can have another array of the same size where you store the partial sums. Then, whenever you are given the bounds you can just subtract the partial sums and you get the sum of elements in that interval. For example:

```
Elements:    1 2 3 4  5  6
Partial_Sum: 1 3 6 10 15 21
```

Lets, say that the array starts at index=0, and you want the sum of elements in the interval [1, 3] inclusive:

```
// subtract 1 from the index of the second sum, because we
// want the starting element of the interval to be included.
Partial_Sum[3] - Partial_Sum[1-1] = 10 - 1 = 9
```

Comment: Good answer. If the items are sorted (i.e. the range is specified as values rather than indexes), the algorithm is O(log n).  Actually 2 * log n, because it'll take two lookups with a binary search.

Comment: @Jim Mischel Surely computing Partial_Sum is O(N) (you have to visit every element at least once - there's just no way around that) and computing the sum between a and b is O(1) (constant time), provided indexing into your array is also constant time. If you expect to compute sums for lots of different values of a and b on the same array then this will be significantly faster otherwise not so much. Also, with the implementation above - watch out for a=0 since it will try to index Partial_Sum[-1].

Comment: @Adam Bowen: As I said in my comment, *if the range is specified as values rather than indexes* into the array, then you'll have to do a binary search to find the indexes of the values. And, yes, there is pre-processing time--that was assumed. There's no point in computing the partial sums if you're only going to do this once for a particular array.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to recall that [prefix sums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum) can be used to answer such queries in `O(lg n)` time.

EDIT: I was a little too quick there - it can be done even faster. If you spend `O(n)` time (and `O(n)` extra memory) precomputing the prefix sum array (on a single-core computer), the answer to each query can be found in `O(1)` time by subtracting the appropriate elements of that array. If you happen to have `n` processors available, the precomputation can be done in `O(lg n)` time.

Comment: +1: No. I don't think you are overcomplicating! This works with dynamic arrays, and instead of SUM, it works with _any_ associative (we can probably drop the requirement of commutative) operation. FOr instance MIN, MAX, GreatestCommonDivisor, LeastCommonMultiple etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

I must be missing something about the question. Given an array of partial sums, you should be able to get constant complexity -- the sum of elements from `a` to `b` is `partial_sums[b] - partial_sums[a]` (or if you can't assume `a<b`, `partial_sums[max(a,b)] - partial_sums[min(a,b)]`).

Perhaps you're talking about `a` and `b` as bounds on the values rather than the location? If so, then assuming your array is sorted, you can get O(log N) complexity by using a binary search for the locations of `a` and `b`, then subtracting as above. If the array isn't (and can't be) sorted, you can accomplish the same by creating an array of references to the original objects, sorting the references, and generating partial sums for those references. That adds work to the preprocessing, but keeps O(log N) for the queries.

Edit: Making the array(s) dynamic should have no effect, at least in terms of computational complexity. If you only ever insert/delete at the end of the main array, you can insert/delete in constant time in the partial sums array as well. For an insertion, you do something like:

```
N = N + 1
main_array[N] = new_value
partial_sum[N] = partial_sum[N-1] + new_value
```

To delete from the end, you just use `N = N - 1`, and ignore the values previously at the ends of both arrays.

If you need to support insertion/deletion in the middle of the main array, that takes linear time. Updating the partial sums array can be done in linear time as well. For example, to insert `new_value` at index `i`, you'd do something like:

```
N = N + 1
for location = N downto i + 1 
    main_array[location] = main_array[location-1]
    partial_sums[location] = partial_sums[location-1] + new_value
```

Deleting is similar, except that you work your way up from the deletion point to the end, and subtract the value being deleted.

I did say "should" for a reason though -- there is a possible caveat. If your array is extremely dynamic *and* the contents are floating point, you can/will run into a problem: repeatedly adding and subtracting values as you insert/delete elements may (and eventually *will*) lead to rounding errors. Under these circumstances, you have a couple of choices: one is to abandon the idea altogether. Another uses even more storage -- as you add/delete items, keep a running sum of the absolute values of the elements that have been added/subtracted. When/if this exceeds a chosen percentage of the partial sum for that point, you re-compute your partial sums (and zero the running sum).

Comment: Perhaps he wants a dynamic array, he can update values at will. In which case a binary tree gives O(logn) insert/access/query times. +1 for addressing the other interpretation, though.

Comment: Yes that's right, as I said in the comments above, the array is dynamic. With your solution I get constant complexity on sum() but linear on change_value()...

Comment: @marco signati: see edited answer. A dynamic array doesn't really change anything.

Comment: @Jerry It changes *everything*. From the viewpoint of complexity, it makes absolutely no sense to keep precomputed sum values for an array whose content constantly changes.

Comment: @RPRPORO: not when updating the sums has the same complexity as updating the values themselves. It's quite routine, for example, to update database indexes as data is added or deleted. Granted, if the insertion/deletion rate is high *enough*, you may be better off without an index, but the mere possibility of insertions/deletions doesn't necessarily mean an index is a bad idea.

Comment: @Jerry Why settle for O(n + log n), when you can have O(n) and a simpler algorithm? And that's not even mentioning space complexity for the precomputation proposal..

Comment: There's no "O(n + log n)" involved anywhere. There's O(n) updating, and O(1) lookups. Your proposal gives O(n) updating and O(n) lookups. In mine, the updates do have a higher constant, but unless lookups are *quite* rare or N is quite small, O(1) will be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Ok maybe I found a solution to have log(n) on both change value and sum, and with a linear space overhead.

I'll try to explain: we build a binary tree, where the leaves are the array values, in the order they are in the array (not sorted, not a sorted tree).

Then we create the tree bottom-up merging 2 leaves at a time, and putting their sum in the parent. For example if the array has length 4 and values [1,5,3,2], we'll have a tree with 3 levels, the root will be the total sum (11) and the others will be 1+5->6 and 3+2->5

now, to change a value we have to update this tree (log n), and to compute the sum I worked out this algorithm (log n):

acc = 0 // accumulator

starting from the lower bound, we go up the tree. I we go up left (current node is the right child) then acc += current_node - parent_node. If we go up right (current node is the left child) we don't do anything.

we then do the same from the upper bound, of course in this case it's the opposite (we do the sum if we go up right)

we do this alternating, once on the lower bound, once on the upper bound. If we have that the 2 node we reach are actually the same node, we then sum the value of that node to the accumulator, and return the accumulator.

I know I didn't explain it well.. I'm having some difficulty in explaining..
Anyone understood?

Comment: (In other words: I am very certain that this algorithm works, and that your time and space bounds are correct.)

Comment: @marco The total complexity for this algorithm is O(N + log N): O(N) for the sum + O(log N) for the update. This is still higher than O(N). Please see my answer below (or above). (:

Comment: @RPR: This is a data structure problem. You are to create an 'array' structure which supports querying for range sums. So calling it Omega(N) is not really correct.

Comment: @Moron You are assuming the content of the array is static (in which case it would be appropriate to precompute some or all sum ranges), as opposed to what the author of the question has stated as the problem: "the array is dynamic, values can change, and I don't want to have linear complexity to change a value!", therefore, the optimal solution to this problem is O(N).

Comment: @RPR: No, I am not assuming the content of array is static... What gave you that impression? An array structure by default supports accessing/updating by index. An extra added burden is able to support range sums. No way does that imply a static array.

Comment: @Moron The only reasonable way the complexity of solving the posed problem can be somehow stated as something different from O(N) is by assuming that the values of the array are static and thus, amenable to precomputation. When I write that you are assuming the content of the array is static, I'm being polite and assuming you are being reasonable about this. (:

Comment: @RPR: What I said was that I will have an array class which supports updates/access/range sum. You start out empty, and then _use_ that structure as your array. All operations are O(logn) if you use binary trees. Even if we are given an input array of size N, we can still construct a tree out of it in O(N) time, and then amortize that cost over different queries. Sorry, and I thought I was being polite! You seem to have missed what the question is about...

Comment: @RPRPORO My assumption is that the data is not static, and that he intends to perform a lot of queries. Hence, he is presumably willing to pay a high preprocessing cost in exchange for rapid searches and value updates. The algorithm he describes has a preprocessing cost of `O(n)`, a search cost of `O(lg n)` and an update cost (of a single value) of `O(lg n)`. The complexity analysis of many search-related algorithms assume that the preprocessing has already been done - for instance, we say that binary search is `O(lg n)` even though sorting the array takes `O(n lg n)`.

Comment: @Moron, @Aasmund: The data contained in the array is dynamic, which means it can change entirely each and every time the algorithm is executed over it, thus: *from the viewpoint of complexity it is entirely pointless, and counterproductive to precompute anything*. There is no need for search, there is no need for precomputation, the answer to the poster's questions is simply that he cannot reduce the complexity from O(N) for this particular problem.

Comment: @RPR: You are still not getting it. Once you precompute the binary tree, any changes you make to the array can be done in O(logn) time in the tree... The point is you work with the _new_ data-structure.

Comment: @Moron: You don't have to make any changes to the array in order to compute the answer to the stated problem, employing a binary tree in this instance is actually counterproductive from the viewpoint of complexity.

Comment: @RPR: Just having a datastructure which supports exactly _one_ query is pointless. You did notice the data-structure tag, didn't you?

Comment: @Moron Designing an algorithm that solves in O(n + log n) a problem that can be solved with a simpler algorithm in O(n) is not only pointless, but also irrational. No data structure or algorithm can reduce the complexity of *the stated problem* from O(n). Please review the stated problem.

Comment: @Marco Excuse the noise, please see my answer below (or above). (:

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases: static data or dynamic (varying) data

#### 1. Static data

For static data this is a well known problem. First compute the "sum table" (an array of n+1 elements):

```
st[0] = 0;
for (int i=0,n=x.size(); x<n; x++)
    st[i] = st[i-1] + x[i];
```

then to compute the sum of the elements between `a` and `b` you just need to do

```
sum = st[b] - st[a];
```

The algorithm can also be used in higher dimensions. For example if you need to compute the sum of all the values between (x0, y0) and (x1, y1) you can just do

```
sum = st[y0][x0] + st[y1][x1] - st[y0][x1] - st[y1][x0];
```

where `st[y][x]` is the sum of all elements above and to the left of `(x, y)`.

The computing of the sum table is a **O(n)** operation (where **n** is the number of elements, for example `rows*columns` for a 2d matrix), but for very large data sets (e.g. images) it's possible to write an [optimal parallel version](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch39.html) that can run in **O(n/m)** where **m** is the number of available CPUs. This is something I found quite surprising...

To do a simple (single-threaded) sum table computation in the 2d case:

```
for (int y=0; y<h; y++)
  for (int x=0; x<w; x++)
    st[y+1][x+1] = st[y+1][x] + st[y][x+1] - st[y][x] + value[y][x];
```

#### 2.Dynamic data

For dynamic data instead you can use what could be called a "multiresolution" approach:

```
void addDelta(std::vector< std::vector< int > >& data,
              int index, int delta)
{
    for (int level=0,n=data.size(); level<n; level++)
    {
        data[level][index] += delta;
        index >>= 1;
    }
}

int sumToIndex(std::vector< std::vector< int > >& data,
               int index)
{
    int result = 0;
    for (int level=0,n=data.size(); level<n; level++)
    {
        if (index & 1) result += data[level][index-1];
        index >>= 1;
    }
    return result;
}

int sumRange(std::vector< std::vector< int > >& data,
             int a, int b)
{
    return sumToIndex(data, b) - sumToIndex(data, a);
}
```

Basically at each "level" a cell holds the sums of two cells of the next finer levels. When you add a data to the lowest (higher-resolution) level you also have to add it to the higher levels (this is what `addDelta` does).
To compute the sum of all values from 0 to `x` you can use higher levels to save up computation... see the following picture:

[image]

Finally to get the sum from `a` to `b` you simply compute the difference between those two sums starting from 0.

Comment: Hmm...how exactly you compute N^2 values in only O(N) operations?

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: It's **o(n)** where n is the size of the input (that for a 2d matrix is `rows*columns`). I added an explanation of how to build the 2d sum table with a single pass and a link to an article explaining how to use massively parallel hw (CUDA) to speedup this computation.

Comment: For a simpler way of stating this, please see my answer below (or above). (:

Comment: Actually the optimum complexity of the parallel computation for case 1 (the case stated by the question's author), is O(n/m + m + 1).

Comment: Yes, good answer, it's the same idea I used in my algorithm with the binary tree! Maybe this version is easier to implement/explain..

Answer (score 0):

According to the problem statement, you are given an array of numbers, and a pair of indices representing the bounds of an interval which contents are to be summed. Since there is no *search* involved in this problem, representing the data as a binary tree structure offers no advantage in terms of time or space complexity.

Since you are *not* allowed to execute your solution in a multi-processor environment, you are "stuck" with O(N).

If your solution were allowed to execute in a multi-processor environment, the optimal complexity would be O(N/p + p + 1), where p is the number of processors available. This is due to the fact that, in this case, you would have been able to divide the interval into p sub-intervals (+1), sum the intervals in parallel (N/p), and then sum the result of each individual sub-interval (+p), to complete the calculation.

Comment: Not stuck with O (N) if you consider that the same task will be performed multiple times. For example, given a million different intervals [a, b], surely you don't need a million times N operations.

Answer (score 0):

Create a balanced binary tree sorting the numbers according to their value. This can be done so that each operation takes linear time. In each node store the sum of all values below that node. To calculate the sum of values in the range [a, b] you have to go down that tree both for a and b and add the appropriate values. O (ln n) every time you calculate a sum or change a value.